# Unable to check condition using filter method from Observables, Throwing that condition property as undefined

Tags: angular

auth.service.ts

```
  getUsers(): Observable<object> {
return this.http.get<{message: string, users: any}>(this.baseUrl).pipe(map(responseData => responseData.users))}
```

userlist.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.users$ = this.authService.getUsers().pipe(filter((user: any) =>  user.role == "0"));}
```

When I tried to filter the Observable, I am not able to check condition through any properties with user keyword, It's simply throws role as undefined.

```
this.users$ = this.authService.getUsers()
```

If I simply use this above syntax, It's working without any issues. How to make the filter method works.

I don't want to subscribe `this.users$` and do filter functionality. Instead I need to map in Observable itself. Kindly anyone provide solution for the same.

Edited:
Finally I got update through some other posts. But I couldn't really understand how it's working. Can anyone help me here

```
  this.users$ = this.authService.getUsers().pipe(
  tap((users: any) => console.log("****** user", users)),
  map(users => users.filter((user: User) => user.role == "0")))
```

Thanks to @johey who really helps to me add tap method.

Comment: At first sight it looks correct. Have you tried to debug or output the received user? You could e.g. add tap(user => console.log(user)) before the filter.

Comment: Thanks for your timely help @johey. After adding tap method, I am able to get the answer which I added at last in my question itself. But I couldn't understand how it's works. could you please explain if possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just adding that line probably didn't fix your problem as it just outputs the users to the console. Maybe your HTTP service was giving a different response before?